# SessionManagerListener not working

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm working with an app and I'm trying to cast a video, but when I want to setup a listener to the cast session is not working. I'm working within a fragment, so I can't figure it out where the problem is.

```
private void setupCastListener() {
        mSessionManagerListener = new SessionManagerListener<CastSession>() {

            @Override
            public void onSessionEnded(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResumed(CastSession session, boolean wasSuspended) {
                Log.d("fragment tv", "onSessionResumed");

                onApplicationConnected(session);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResumeFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStarted(CastSession session, String sessionId){                    Log.d("fragment tv", "onSessionStarted");
                onApplicationConnected(session);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStartFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStarting(CastSession session) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionEnding(CastSession session) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResuming(CastSession session, String sessionId) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionSuspended(CastSession session, int reason) {
            }

            private void onApplicationConnected(CastSession castSession) {
                Log.d("fragment tv", "connected");
                mCastSession = castSession;
                mLocation = PlaybackLocation.REMOTE;}

            private void onApplicationDisconnected() {
                Log.d("fragment tv", "disconnected");

                mLocation = PlaybackLocation.LOCAL;

            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Where/how do you register this listener?

Comment: I found where the problem was, I forgot this line of code, `mCastContext.getSessionManager().addSessionManagerListener(
                mSessionManagerListener, CastSession.class);`

Answer (score 2):

***fault 1*** :- usually people forgot to register listener in `onResume` method

```
onResume(){
   mCastContext.getSessionManager()
               .addSessionManagerListener(mSessionManagerListener, CastSession.class);
}
```

***fault 2*** :- Some people add `MediaRouteButton` on `home screen` and write `SessionManagerListener` in different activity and forget to add `MediaRouteButton` on that `scrren`. So, obviously the `SessionManagerListener` will never get called.

So, be careful to add `MediaRouteButton` and then add `SessionManagerListener` on corresponding activity.

```
MediaRouteButton mMediaRouteButton;

onCreateView(){
...
...
       setupCastListener(); // initialize listener variable
       mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(getActivity());

       // add and setup mMediaRouteButton - CastButtonFactory
       mMediaRouteButton = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
       CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getContext(), mMediaRouteButton);
...
...
}
```